# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLButtonElement] has no size and location

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using this Python code to select a date in a calendar. However, I am encountering an error when trying to click on the previous or next button. Before attempting to use the method to click next or previous until I reach the desired date, I tried to select the month and year from a dropdown menu. Unfortunately, I have been unable to scroll up to access the months and years that are not currently visible.

```
desired_day = "1"
desired_month = "April"
desired_year = "2022"
        # Find the date picker element
        date_picker = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.start-date > div.control-box__icon")
        
        # Click on the date picker to open the calendar
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(date_picker).click().perform()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xdsoft_month > span")))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xdsoft_year > span")))

        
        # Map the names of the months to their order in the year (0-11)
        months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
        month_values = {month: i for i, month in enumerate(months)}
        
        while True:
            # Find the currently selected month and year
            current_month_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.xdsoft_monthpicker .xdsoft_label.xdsoft_month > span")
            current_year_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.xdsoft_monthpicker .xdsoft_label.xdsoft_year > span")
            
            current_month = current_month_element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
            current_year = current_year_element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
            
            print(f"Current month element: {current_month_element}")
            print(f"Current year element: {current_year_element}")
            print(f"Current month: {current_month}")
            print(f"Current year: {current_year}")


            
            # If the currently selected month and year are the desired ones, break the loop
            if (current_month == desired_month) and (current_year == desired_year):
                break
            
            # If the current month or year is not found, print an error message and break the loop
            if current_month is None or current_year is None:
                print("Error: Current month or year not found.")
                break
            # If the desired date is in the future, click on the next button; otherwise, click on the prev button
            if (int(current_year) < int(desired_year)) or (int(current_year) == int(desired_year) and month_values[current_month] < month_values[desired_month]):
                next_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.xdsoft_monthpicker button.xdsoft_next")
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(next_button).click().perform()
            else:
                prev_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.xdsoft_monthpicker button.xdsoft_prev")
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(prev_button).click().perform()


        # Find the day element
        day_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//td[@data-date='{desired_day}']")

        # Click on the day element
        day_element.click()
            
        while True:
            response = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
            testPosition = response.css("div[data-col-type='position']::text").get()
            if testPosition:
                break
```

```
Scraping: https://expectedscore.com/division/england/premier-league/
Waiting for it to load...
Current month element: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7e5307747ac61c242996e2762e46f577", element="2B9FD2C80259E3D8297126104DA5707B_element_708")>
Current year element: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7e5307747ac61c242996e2762e46f577", element="2B9FD2C80259E3D8297126104DA5707B_element_709")>
Current month: August
Current year: 2022
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\Desktop\02_Projects\01_Work\01_PythonScript\testmoment.py", line 269, in <module>
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(prev_button).click().perform()
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
    self.w3c_actions.perform()
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\actions\action_builder.py", line 76, in perform
    self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLButtonElement] has no size and location
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.110)
```

```
`<div class="xdsoft_datetimepicker xdsoft_noselect xdsoft_tbl-calendar" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 1688.62px; top: 394.6px;"><div class="xdsoft_datepicker active"><div class="xdsoft_monthpicker"><button type="button" class="xdsoft_prev" style="visibility: visible;"></button><button type="button" class="xdsoft_today_button" style="visibility: visible;"></button><div class="xdsoft_label xdsoft_month"><span>August</span><div class="xdsoft_select xdsoft_monthselect xdsoft_scroller_box" style="display: none;"><div style="margin-top: 0px;"><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="0">January</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1">February</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2">March</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="3">April</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="4">May</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="5">June</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="6">July</div><div class="xdsoft_option xdsoft_current" data-value="7">August</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="8">September</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="9">October</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="10">November</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="11">December</div></div><div class="xdsoft_scrollbar"><div class="xdsoft_scroller" style="height: 10px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></div></div><i></i></div><div class="xdsoft_label xdsoft_year"><span>2022</span><div class="xdsoft_select xdsoft_yearselect xdsoft_scroller_box" style="display: none;"><div style="margin-top: 0px;"><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1950">1950</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1951">1951</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1952">1952</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1953">1953</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1954">1954</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1955">1955</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1956">1956</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1957">1957</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1958">1958</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1959">1959</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1960">1960</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1961">1961</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1962">1962</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1963">1963</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1964">1964</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1965">1965</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1966">1966</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1967">1967</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1968">1968</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1969">1969</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1970">1970</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1971">1971</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1972">1972</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1973">1973</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1974">1974</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1975">1975</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1976">1976</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1977">1977</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1978">1978</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1979">1979</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1980">1980</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1981">1981</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1982">1982</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1983">1983</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1984">1984</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1985">1985</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1986">1986</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1987">1987</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1988">1988</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1989">1989</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1990">1990</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1991">1991</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1992">1992</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1993">1993</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1994">1994</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1995">1995</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1996">1996</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1997">1997</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1998">1998</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="1999">1999</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2000">2000</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2001">2001</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2002">2002</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2003">2003</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2004">2004</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2005">2005</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2006">2006</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2007">2007</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2008">2008</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2009">2009</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2010">2010</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2011">2011</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2012">2012</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2013">2013</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2014">2014</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2015">2015</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2016">2016</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2017">2017</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2018">2018</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2019">2019</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2020">2020</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2021">2021</div><div class="xdsoft_option xdsoft_current" data-value="2022">2022</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2023">2023</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2024">2024</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2025">2025</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2026">2026</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2027">2027</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2028">2028</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2029">2029</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2030">2030</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2031">2031</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2032">2032</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2033">2033</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2034">2034</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2035">2035</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2036">2036</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2037">2037</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2038">2038</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2039">2039</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2040">2040</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2041">2041</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2042">2042</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2043">2043</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2044">2044</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2045">2045</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2046">2046</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2047">2047</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2048">2048</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2049">2049</div><div class="xdsoft_option " data-value="2050">2050</div></div><div class="xdsoft_scrollbar"><div class="xdsoft_scroller" style="height: 10px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></div></div><i></i></div><button type="button" class="xdsoft_next" style="visibility: visible;"></button></div><div class="xdsoft_calendar"><table><thead><tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td data-date="31" data-month="6" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week0 xdsoft_date xdsoft_other_month xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>31</div></td><td data-date="1" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week1 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>1</div></td><td data-date="2" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week2 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>2</div></td><td data-date="3" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week3 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>3</div></td><td data-date="4" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week4 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>4</div></td><td data-date="5" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week5 xdsoft_date xdsoft_current xdsoft_today" title=""><div>5</div></td><td data-date="6" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week6 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>6</div></td></tr><tr><td data-date="7" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week0 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>7</div></td><td data-date="8" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week1 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>8</div></td><td data-date="9" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week2 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>9</div></td><td data-date="10" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week3 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>10</div></td><td data-date="11" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week4 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>11</div></td><td data-date="12" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week5 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>12</div></td><td data-date="13" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week6 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>13</div></td></tr><tr><td data-date="14" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week0 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>14</div></td><td data-date="15" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week1 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>15</div></td><td data-date="16" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week2 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>16</div></td><td data-date="17" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week3 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>17</div></td><td data-date="18" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week4 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>18</div></td><td data-date="19" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week5 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>19</div></td><td data-date="20" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week6 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>20</div></td></tr><tr><td data-date="21" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week0 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>21</div></td><td data-date="22" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week1 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>22</div></td><td data-date="23" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week2 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>23</div></td><td data-date="24" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week3 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>24</div></td><td data-date="25" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week4 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>25</div></td><td data-date="26" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week5 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>26</div></td><td data-date="27" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week6 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>27</div></td></tr><tr><td data-date="28" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week0 xdsoft_date xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>28</div></td><td data-date="29" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week1 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>29</div></td><td data-date="30" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week2 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>30</div></td><td data-date="31" data-month="7" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week3 xdsoft_date" title=""><div>31</div></td><td data-date="1" data-month="8" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week4 xdsoft_date xdsoft_other_month" title=""><div>1</div></td><td data-date="2" data-month="8" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week5 xdsoft_date xdsoft_other_month" title=""><div>2</div></td><td data-date="3" data-month="8" data-year="2022" class="xdsoft_date xdsoft_day_of_week6 xdsoft_date xdsoft_other_month xdsoft_weekend" title=""><div>3</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><button type="button" class="xdsoft_save_selected blue-gradient-button" style="display: none;">Save Selected</button></div><div class="xdsoft_timepicker"><button type="button" class="xdsoft_prev"></button><div class="xdsoft_time_box xdsoft_scroller_box"><div class="xdsoft_time_variant" style="margin-top: 0px;"><div class="xdsoft_time xdsoft_current" data-hour="0" data-minute="0">00:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="1" data-minute="0">01:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="2" data-minute="0">02:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="3" data-minute="0">03:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="4" data-minute="0">04:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="5" data-minute="0">05:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="6" data-minute="0">06:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="7" data-minute="0">07:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="8" data-minute="0">08:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="9" data-minute="0">09:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="10" data-minute="0">10:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="11" data-minute="0">11:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="12" data-minute="0">12:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="13" data-minute="0">13:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="14" data-minute="0">14:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="15" data-minute="0">15:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="16" data-minute="0">16:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="17" data-minute="0">17:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="18" data-minute="0">18:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="19" data-minute="0">19:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="20" data-minute="0">20:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="21" data-minute="0">21:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="22" data-minute="0">22:00</div><div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="23" data-minute="0">23:00</div></div><div class="xdsoft_scrollbar"><div class="xdsoft_scroller" style="height: 10px; margin-top: 0px;"></div></div></div><button type="button" class="xdsoft_next"></button></div></div>`
```

Comment: Does that css selector potentially navigate to multiple elements on the website?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes the CSS selector div.xdsoft_monthpicker button.xdsoft_next and div.xdsoft_monthpicker button.xdsoft_prev are returning two results for each.

Comment: that is most likely you're problem. I'd bet that the element being selected is the one that isn't visible. If you leave a link to the website, I could help you find a good by location for the element. Do you need to use css selectors?

Comment: Thx for your help, here is the website. What I try to achieve is to select a custom start date to get the data for the last 8 for example in the main full script. https://expectedscore.com/division/england/premier-league/?COUNTRY_CODE=england&DIVISION_CODE=premier-league

Comment: What I tried first on the website was to click on the calendar > click on the month > select the month, but when the month was not visible, I couldn't achieve to scroll until the month was visible and the same for the year

Comment: After I tried another method to scroll up. To modify <div style="margin-top: -130px;"> but same result couldn't achieve to do it, and at the end I got the idea to try to use prev and use button to achieve what I wanted (I'm beginner)

Comment: I've been looking for a better way to do this, and I think your best option is to just copy the full xpath here

Comment: `next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xdsoft_datetimepicker xdsoft_noselect xdsoft_tbl-calendar']//div[@class='xdsoft_monthpicker']//button[@class='xdsoft_next']")
                next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xdsoft_monthpicker button.xdsoft_next")))` I achieved to make it work to use xpath and break for next and prev, thx for your recommendation.

Comment: `prev_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xdsoft_datetimepicker xdsoft_noselect xdsoft_tbl-calendar']//div[@class='xdsoft_monthpicker']//button[@class='xdsoft_prev']")
                prev_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.xdsoft_monthpicker button.xdsoft_prev:nth-child(1)")))`